# Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I would like to control which properties from my model are serialized to my WebAPI2 JSON response, based on matching a query parameter to an attribute. I mainly want to do this to reduce bandwidth on GETs without causing a proliferation of ViewModel classes. For example:

```
GET /books/1?format=summary

public class Book
{
    [SerializeFormat("summary")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SerializeFormat("summary")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Contents { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
[SerializeFormat("summary","Id","Title")]
public class Book
{ ... }
```

To do this myself, I could derive all of my model classes from a custom base implementing `ISerializable`. In `ISerializable.GetObjectData()`, iterate through all properties inspecting the attributes. Not sure about performance on this idea.

Don't want to reinvent this solution, though if it already exists as a package.

Comment: Possibly [Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) could help.

Comment: At the time the JSON is serialized, is the query parameter available so that custom `JsonSerializerSettings` could be selected?

Comment: Yes the query parameters are available then. I don't see `JsonSerializerSettings` helping though. Would you please expand on your idea a little? It would be a really long walk to make conditional property serialization do this job, involving duplicating every property on a class. It appears to be meant respond to model content, not request content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to introduce a custom [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute` that can be applied to properties and fields:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute(string filterName)
    {
        this.FilterName = filterName;
    }

    public string FilterName { get; private set; }
}
```

Next, subclass [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm), override [`CreateProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperty.htm), and return null for properties that have at least one `[JsonConditionalInclude]` applied, none of which match the a filter supplied to the contract resolver:

```
public class JsonConditionalIncludeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public JsonConditionalIncludeContractResolver(string filterName)
    {
        this.FilterName = filterName;
    }

    public string FilterName { get; set; }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        // Properties without JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute applied are serialized unconditionally.
        // Properties with JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute are serialized only if one of the attributes
        // has a matching filter name.
        var attrs = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute), true);
        if (attrs.Count > 0 && !attrs.Cast<JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute>().Any(a => a.FilterName == FilterName))
            return null;
        return property;
    }
}
```

Finally, when serializing your class to JSON, set [`JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ContractResolver.htm) equal to your custom contract resolver, initializing the `FilterName` from your web request, for instance:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalInclude("summary")]
    [JsonConditionalInclude("title")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalInclude("summary")]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalInclude("title")]
    [JsonConditionalInclude("citation")]
    public string Property4 { get; set; }

    [JsonConditionalInclude("citation")]
    public string Field1;

    public static void Test()
    {
        var test = new TestClass { Property1 = "a", Property2 = "b", Property3 = "c", Property4 = "d", Field1 = "e" };
        Test(test, "summary"); // Prints "a", "b" and "c"
        Test(test, "title");   // Prints "a", "b" and "d".
        Test(test, "citation");// Prints "e", "a" and "d"
        Test(test, null);      // Prints "e", "a", "b", "c" and "d".
    }

    public static string Test(TestClass test, string webRequestFormat)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new JsonConditionalIncludeContractResolver(webRequestFormat) };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented, settings);

        Debug.WriteLine(json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

The contract resolver will apply to all classes being serialized, not just the root class, which looks to be what you want.

Comment: I like your idea. It's nice that your attribute is optional. To be ideal for me it will also need to handle a default filter state, perhaps an empty string, such that the attribute is set and one of the explicit matching scenarios is when no "format" has been applied. I'll actually have to subclass `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` instead, and then I can just apply it in my WebApiConfig across the entire site.

Comment: @sbc Is it possible to handle the condition within the JsonConditionalIncludeAttribute itself without the JsonConditionalIncludeContractResolver? I'm refactoring some code that has a lot of child classes (the child classes have collections of the top parent class --it goes about 5th gen down) and I need that property for some of the classes. If it's included it causes an endless recursion loop so I'd like to serialize it conditionally. I looked into the code of the included Newtonsoft attributes but didn't get a clue.

Comment: @AdamMendoza - A custom resolver is required here, but there may be some other way to achieve what you need, so you should ask another question with a [mcve].  The contract resolver applies to all classes, so depth isn't an issue when using a custom resolver.  One possibility would be to use a custom resolver that sets a `ShouldSerialize` method when required.  Or maybe setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm) will do what you need.

Comment: @dbc Thanks! JsonSerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling does not do the trick. I also looked at the code of the NewtonSoft library JsonIgnore and it's empty. After I posted the question I also though to look into the contract resolver. Thanks! If I get stuck I'll post a demo project.