# UWP: How to Serialize different properties in single class into Local Vs. Roaming using DataMembers in JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, win-universal-app

Using C# and Json.Net, I have multiple properties inside of a single class (Mostly INT and STRING values).  Most of the properties are going to be stored into the local app folder, since they can't be roamed due to another, unrelated problem.  However, I would like to roam one of the values.

The local values are stored at the following location:

```
StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.
            CreateFolderAsync("Assets\\", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

The roaming value is stored at the following location:

```
            StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.
            CreateFolderAsync("Assets\\", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

My specific question is, how do I mark a property with a DataContract, so that it will serialize a specific way?

```
public class ExampleClass_Model
{
   [JsonIgnore]
   private int _roamingDataToStore;

   public int RoamingDataToStore
   {
   get { return _roamingDataToStore; }
   set { _roamingDataToStore = value; }
   }

   [JsonIgnore]
   private int _localDataOneToStore;

   public int LocalDataOneToStore
   {
   get { return _localDataOneToStore; }
   set { _localDataOneToStore= value; }
   }


   [JsonIgnore]
   private int _localDataTwoToStore;

   public int LocalDataTwoToStore
   {
   get { return _localDataTwoToStore; }
   set { _localDataTwoToStore= value; }
   }


    public async Task<bool> WriteDataAsync()
    {
        Functions.WriteData writeData = new Functions.WriteData();
        bool successfulWrite = await writeData.WriteJSONDataFile(this);
        if (successfulWrite) { writeData = null; }
        return successfulWrite;
    }
}
```

However, when the WriteDataAsync() method passes the entire class to be serialized, it can only be serialized to local or roaming folders.  What I am trying to do is have the single roaming property roam, without creating a whole new model class.

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: You can use `JsonConditionalIncludeContractResolver` from [Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713847), then use one contract resolver for the roaming data, and another for local data.  In fact, I think this might be a duplicate question; agree?

Comment: It might be.  I apologize if so...I checked every key word I knew to think of.  Let me carefully read through your link.  Thank you.