# Custom JSON serializer

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonserializer

I have a class,

```
partial class Customer
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Address{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CardInfo { get; set; }         

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

when I serialize this, the customerId is not there. And that's how I wanted it to work.
I have a separate method where I need to send the customerId back. so may be I should use a custom serializer? is there a way to achieve this using the same class.

Comment: What does your code look like that is serializing the Customer class?

Comment: If this is something you need to do with multiple properties in multiple types, you could consider using the answer from [Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713847/conditional-member-serialization-based-on-query-parameter).

Comment: @Jeff  I am just using json.net in built converter. JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [conditional serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) feature of JSON.Net:

```
partial class Customer
{
    // Ignoring the property since it's only used to indicate if we should serialize
    // CustomerId or not
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IncludeCustomerId {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Address{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CardInfo { get; set; }         

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCustomerId()
    {
        return IncludeCustomerId;
    }
}
```

Now Json.Net will only serialize `CustomerId` if you set `IncludeCustomerId` to `true`.