# How can I have different serialization options for DocumentDB and BLOB storage?

Tags: json.net, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I've a class and I need to save it both in DocumentDB and in BLOB storage.

```
public class MessagesSetType
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustomerSubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
    public MessageSetTypeCollection Messages { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

In DocumentDB I have to save all properties EXCEPT `Messages` then in BLOB storage I must save all properties included `Messages`.

So my question is: how is the prettiest way to exclude the Messages property from DocumentDB and not from BLOB?
I've tought to create a clone of this class without the `Messages` property then save it to DocumentDB and save the original class to BLOB but this solution doesn't satisfy me..

Comment: Can you use a different contract resolver for each, along the lines of [Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713847/conditional-member-serialization-based-on-query-parameter) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the same class. Simply because we can re-use does not mean it's a good idea. The purpose and usage of each store differs, which means that they may very well diverge further. How do you know if it's the same item from different stores or if it is different items? Instead of having clean and explicit implementations you may very well find yourself with a some implicit monster of assumptions.

The storage and usage is different. What you store and retrieve from blob and DocumentDB is not the same thing. Be explicit.

Comment: I agree with hsulriksen. Consider creating sperate classes for `MessagesMetaData` (to be stored in DocumentDB) and `Messages` (to be stored in Blob Storage). For the `MessagesMetaData` class, you can create an "attachment" that is simply a reference to the URI for the messages in blob store.