# Building a custom JSON serializer that isn't invoked by default

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Newtownsoft JSON.Net and want to add custom attributes, then have a JSONConverter that deals with these custom attributes. Currently the way to do this is `[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]`. But I don't want this converter to always be called, only when I pass it into `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...)`. This is because this class is being used by two different paths, one of which needs to modify the JSON based on the properties and the other doesn't.

In other words, I only want these attributes to be considered when I explicitly tell my code to consider them. They should be ignored when Newtonsoft is doing its default serialization. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
class Foo {
    [CustomAttributeToAddMyExtraProperty]
    public int Bar;

    [JsonProperty('default')]
    public int Baz;
}
```

If I just use the default Newtonsoft JSON.Net serialize, I should get

```
{
    "Bar":value1,
    "default":value2
}
```

But if I pass in my custom converter explicitly, I should get this:

```
{
    "Bar":value1,
    "default":value2,
    "MyExtraProperty":value3
}
```

Notice that the JSON.Net attributes are always used.

**UPDATE**

I have tried this:

```
namespace Project1
{
    class Class1
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Class2 foo = new Class2();
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new BlahResolver() }));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class Class2
    {
        [Blah]
        public int one = 1;

        [JsonProperty]
        public int two = 2;

        [Blah]
        public string three = "3";
    }

    internal class BlahAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    class BlahResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            var attr = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(BlahAttribute), true);

            if (attr.Count == 1)
            {
                property.Converter = new BlahConverter();
            }
            return property;
        }
    }

    class BlahConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.IsValueType;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return existingValue;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Parse("{ \"foo\":\"a\", \"bar\":34 }");
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"one":{"foo":"a","bar":34},"two":2,"three":{"foo":"a","bar":34}}
```

I'm able to successfully identify properties with my custom attribute and redirect them to my custom converter. The issue now is the converter is adding properties as if `one` is a complex type. I want to add the properties in the top level JSON, not as properties of `one`.

Output I want:

```
{"one":1, "foo":"a","bar":34,"two":2,"three":3,"foo":"a","bar":34}
```

I realize that this has multiple properties with the same name. I don't know if that's valid or not, but eventually the object value will be included in the name (ex. `one_foo`, `one_bar`), so you can disregard that.

Comment: typing "[json.net custom converter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)" into google would have been a LOT less work than asking this question.

Comment: See [Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm).

Comment: Something like this maybe?  [Conditional member serialization based on query parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29713847/3744182)

Comment: @SamAxe I already looked at that, from my understanding it requires [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))] which I already mentioned won't work. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dbc and AlexanderPetrov that doesn't seem to let me add my own attributes - I don't want to ignore properties, I want to add new ones to the JSON. But IContractResolver might be able to help.

Comment: @Zarwan if you read the page i linked youd see that your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @SamAxe obviously I did read it, and it was not clear enough for me. Feel free to post an answer with details on how that can be used for the functionality I want. I wouldn't have come to stackoverflow if I was able to get an answer from it. Pointing me to an article that is not clear enough for me is not helpful to me or anyone else who wants to use this question as a reference in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your update, you're very close to getting what you need to work for this scenario. At this point, your only issue is in the WriteJson method.

All you need to do at this point is simply:

```
writer.WritePropertyName("propertyName");
writer.WriteValue("propertyValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a different serializer depending on the current execution path, you are correct that the attribute route will not work

Instead pass in the currently desired converter during the serialization process:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Formatting.Indented, new MyCustomConverter(typeof(MyType)));
```

[Source](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)